# Laravel - Using repository in own class

Tags: php, laravel, repository-pattern

In Laravel 4, I have several interfaces which are currently bound to Eloquent repositories. In my controllers, I'd do:

```
use Acme\Repositories\User\UserRepository;

class UserController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * @var UserRepository
     */
    protected $users;


    public function __construct(UserRepository $users)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
    }
```

I can then access my custom methods to grab data using Eloquent.

However, how do I do this in my own classes?

```
use Acme\Repositories\Notification\NotificationRepository;
use Acme\Services\ServiceInterface;

class HipChatService implements ServiceInterface {

    protected $notifications;

    public function __construct(NotificationRepository $notifications)
    {
        $this->notifications = $notifications;
    }
```

To test in a route:

```
use Acme\Services\HipChat\HipChatService;

Route::get('hipchat', function()
{
    $h = new HipChatService();
});
```

I then get the error:

`Argument 1 passed to Acme\Services\HipChat\HipChatService::__construct() must be an instance of Acme\Repositories\Notification\NotificationRepository, none given`

Now I understand why this happens, but how am I supposed to use the repository within my own class? How am I able to call a controller + method without this happening?

Cheers

Comment: I'm really new on Laravel, but I think that your problem could be that you have to bind the instantiation of the `HipChatService` by sending a `NotificationRepository` instance, then the IoC will do the magic.
Anyways, just reading the code, looks like you cannot call the constructor in that way, the `$notifications` parameter is mandatory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want Laravel to solve your dependencies, you must build your object with `App::make` instead of instanciate manually with new.

```
$myInstance = App::make('Acme\Services\HipChat\HipChatService');
```

Comment: What is App:: ?